# How do I suppress `ffmpeg`'s "Filter ... has an unconnected output" error?

Tags: ffmpeg

If I write something like `ffmpeg -i INPUT.mp4 -filter_complex '[0:v]trim=end=1[test],[0:v]trim=end=2[out]' -map '[out]' OUT.mp4`, I get `Filter trim has an unconnected output`.  This is annoying when debugging my complex filter, because I want to build it up in pieces and not have to worry about useless filters.  How do I suppress this error message while developing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a sink filter at the end of the chain and skip the label.

So,

`'[0:v]trim=end=1[test],[0:v]trim=end=2[out]'`

becomes

`'[0:v]trim=end=1,nullsink;[0:v]trim=end=2[out]'`

Use `anullsink` for audio filters.

P.S. Use `;` to separate filterchains. `,` only between filters inside a linear chain.

Comment: What's the difference between `,` and `;`, semantically?

Comment: @JasonGross `Filters in the same linear chain are separated by commas, and distinct linear chains of filters are separated by semicolons.` - https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-Filtering-Introduction